# Late-Binding Exception Calling Generic Method of Generic Type in C#

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Given the class:

```
public class A<T>
{
    public void Handle(object payload)
    {
        if(IsEnumerable(payload)) //assume this works
        {
            var closedMethod = GetType()
                .GetMethod(
                    "HandleIEnumerable",
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .MakeGenericMethod(
                    GetFirstGenericArgument(typeof(T)));
            closedMethod
                .Invoke(
                    this,
                    null); //Exception thrown by the Invoke operation
                           //Debugging shows type as HandleIEnumerable[T]
            return;
        }
        //handle other things
    }

    //This was added because in the above, I can't interact with "T" 
    //  as IEnumerable<U> without using reflection
    //  to jump through the hoops
    private void HandleIEnumerable<U>(object payload)
    {
        foreach (var element in payload as IEnumerable<U>) 
        {
            // do something to element
        }
    }

    private bool IsEnumerable(object payload) 
    {
        var theType = typeof(T);
        return 
            theType.IsGenericType 
            && (theType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));
    }

    private Type GetFirstGenericArgument(Type t)
    {
        return t.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }
}
```

An exception is exposed by the test case:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void A_Handle_IEnumerable()
    {
        new ClassLibrary1.A<IEnumerable<int>>()
            .Handle(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 } as IEnumerable<int>);
    }
```

Exception details:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Late bound operations cannot be
>   performed on types  or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is
>   true.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 preview express desktop on Windows 7.

1:  How do I make this approach work?

2:  Are generics really the right thing to do here, and if not, suggestions?

*** *answer details* ****

The correct implementation was to just use the IEnumerable [non-generic] to do this:

```
public class A<T>
{
    public void Handle(object payload)
    {
        var enumerable = payload as IEnumerable;
        if(enumerable != null)
        {
            //do work on enumerable
        }
    }
}
```

Ah, the downside of C# as on-the-job training.  All the pain points were due to needing a generic version of IEnumerable, which wasn't needed - only thought it was because I didn't know about the non-generic form.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: Receive an object of unknown type, if it is an IEnumerable iterate over it and do something, and do something else if it is not an IEnumerable.  I tried something much simpler, but everything seemed to need to involve typing IEnumerable<something>, and "something" seems to be only gettable through reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your `GetFirstGenericArgument()` is wrong.
   Calling `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` returns the underlying open generic type.
   Its type argument is `T`.

   Instead, you should write `t.GetGenericArguments()[0]`, which will get the value of the generic type parameter for the closed type.
2. No; your code doesn't make any sense.
   What on earth are you trying to do?

   I suspect that you actually want to write

   ```
   public class CollectionHandler<T> {
       public void Handle(IEnumerable<T> collection) { 
           // Look ma, no reflection!
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Where and how would that hook in to my code?  I gave it a shot but type could not be inferred.

Comment: @PatrickV: After seeing the comment to your question, you actually want to use the non-generic `System.Collections.IEnumerable`, and get rid of generics entirely.

Comment: Thanks SLaks, that did the trick.  Main post updated with details.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to call method `HandleIEnumerable<U>` when you receive instance of `IEnumerable<T>` and U inherits from T.

You can do it without reflection, by specifying that U should inherit from T:

```
  private void HandleIEnumerable<U>(IEnumerable<U> payload) where U :T
  {
    ...
  }
```

And in your Handle method:

```
public void Handle(object payload)
{
    if(IsEnumerable(payload)) 
    {
       HandleIEnumerable((IEnumerable<U>)payload);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no constraint on T.  If and only if T is an IEnumerable<U>, I want to iterate over that enumerable and do something.  But T may be a string as well, in which case I do not want to do that.